# MySQL search with inner select query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I am working on MySQL and i am bit of stuck at one point. i want to fire search query to retrieve the match record from database table. everything works fine but when i am going to search record which i have retrieved using inner select it will not going to be search. i don't know how to fire query for that.

Here is my demo of [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05668/1)

SQL CODE:

```
CREATE TABLE supplier 
(
 supplier_id int auto_increment primary key, 
 supplier_name varchar(20) 
);

INSERT INTO supplier
(supplier_name)
VALUES
('billgate'),
('jobs'),
('zukkerburg');

CREATE TABLE products 
(
 product_id int auto_increment primary key, 
 supplier_id int,
 product_name varchar(20) 
);

INSERT INTO products
(supplier_id,product_name)
VALUES
('1','microsoft'),
('2','apple'),
('3','facebook');
```

Query for retrieve all record:

```
SELECT *,(SELECT supplier_name FROM supplier WHERE supplier_id = products.supplier_id) AS supplier_name FROM products ORDER BY product_id DESC
```

In the above demo if i fire query as below it will give the correct result.

```
SELECT *,(SELECT supplier_name from supplier where supplier_id = products.supplier_id) as supplier_name FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE '%facebook%' ORDER BY product_id desc
```

but i want to search supplier_name from the listing then how can i achieve this?

```
-------------HERE YOUR SQL QUERY (ANSWER)----------
```

Thanks in advance for your help and much appreciated

Comment: Review [this article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) which explains SQL joins. That, rather than a (slow, inefficient) subselect is what you need here.

Comment: Use inner join instead of sub query.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thank nice article.

Comment: @PraDes i am going to use inner join and if not work then get back to you thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  products
INNER JOIN supplier
ON
supplier.supplier_id = products.supplier_id
WHERE
  supplier_name LIKE '%jobs%'
ORDER BY product_id desc;
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ec1c/5)

Another thing, avoid using `LIKE` unless you really have to (in which case additional clauses in WHERE supported by index can speed up the query). Using `LIKE '%something%'`
prevents MySQL from using index (in case you have one).

Comment: He wants to search on  `supplier_name`

Comment: @Zagor23 i know how to accept answer. cheers i am going to accept it. +1 if you like this question. thanks again man :)

Answer (score 4):

try

```
select * From products p,supplier s where p.supplier_id = s.supplier_id
and s.supplier_name='zukkerburg';
```

Comment: Working fine but in your answer search for specific word so need to use LIKE instead of EQUAL(=). thanks :)